# Spring mvc controller - how to do url restrictions

Tags: spring-mvc

This is spring mvc controller /city/{cityName}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/city/{cityName}")
     public String getCity (@PathVariable("cityName") String cityName, Model uiModel) {

}

www.example.com/city/{cityName}
```

Here cityName is dynamically loaded from url, my website can't support some of cityName,
it supports only Bengaluru, Kochin, Hyderabad and Chennai, due to dynamic things
it supports other cities or whatever in the place of cityName, it gives error,
how to restrict cityName for only 4 cities mentioned above.

Is there any way in controller itself or we have to maintain table(hard coded hashtable)

Suggest which is the best way to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll either need separate controller mappings or to look up the `cityName` somewhere. That doesn't have to be hard-coded; you could instead use a YAML or properties file to initialize a `Set` or look it up in a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have the four cities hardcoded in your code, you can also specify them  using regular expression in `@RequestMapping`.

```
@RequestMapping("/cities/{cityName:Bengaluru|Kochin|Hyderabad|Chennai}")
public String getCity(@PathVariable("cityName") String cityName) {

}
```

That way if you specify a city which does not match the allowed values your controller will automatically return HTTP 404.

*Update*: Fixed the sample, the regex should go in `@RequestMapping`, not `@PathVariable`, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Thanks, it works, one small change, instead of Pathvariable make changes in RequestMapping

Comment: Yes, I spotted that mistake and updated the answer about an hour ago. Sorry for that. Anyways, glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

We can do at controller level statically
    @RequestMapping(value = "/city/{cityname:bengaluru|chennai|kochin|hyderabad}")
OR we can create tables, query and put it in hashtable at application start up time.